# Use variable color in component.ts Angular

Tags: css, angular, sass

I have an array of colors that I would like to pass to child component.

```
colors = ['#1e88e5', '#e53935', '#757575'];
```

I can do it as above with the hardcode hex values, but is there a way that I can use the global variable instead like below.

```
colors = [$primary, $secondary, $normal];
```

Since I would like to use the global variable on the component and not on the `scss`, I am not sure how can I use it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can create a class with the right color, and use the class as string instead of color.

Comment: Since your colors are called primary, secondary and accent, I assume they won't chang that much when you input them into your components. 

I would suggest you create a directive for that.

Comment: @trichetriche I have list of more than 100 color variables and would like to use in .ts file for my `charts`. Is there a way I can use that global variables in .ts file

Comment: Then you should definitely group that in a directive.

Answer (score 1):

You can create **class** and pass to the child component

here's is an example,

`color.ts`

```
export class Color {

  $primary = '#ff0000';
  $secondary = '#ffff00';
}
```

in `app.component.ts`

```
import { Color} from './color';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<hello [color]="color"></hello>`
})
export class AppComponent  {
   color = new Color();
}
```

and in `hello.component.ts`

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1 [ngStyle]="{color: color.$primary}">Hello</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() color: any;
```

}

here is [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-in4por?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) demo

Comment: thanks for the reply. Is there a way that I can use the already existing variable color instead of making the variables again? This isn't what I wanted, instead using already existing variables.